# Position Fixed 'button', turned 90 degree, fixed to the right side of the screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

For an assignment I needed to add a div that is turned 90 degrees and is fixed to the right side of the screen, so that if you scroll down, the button moves with the screen.

The problem is that if I turn a div 90 degrees (using either bootstrap or css) the fixed-position does not change and leaves some white space to the right of the div. This while keeping things responsive.

```css
.popup-btn{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height; 100px;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 1%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="popup-btn">
    <a href="#">Example div</a>
</div>
```

I've tried using media queries and positioning the rights with values like right: -5,5% but it is not a very nice way to solve this problem. Does anyone know how to fix a div to right side of the screen properly?

An example of how a button should stick to the side:

[image: example in which button stick to the side]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49096139/8620333

Answer (score 6):

You have to use transform origin to achieve this. Also changed `right: 0` to be `left: 100%` and added `translateX(-50%)` to be always centered on the screen.

Also, you have an error: in height, you are using `;` instead of `:`. I am not sure of is this intended.

Explanation:

- First place the btn outside the screen. That way its top-left corner is the first pixel outside of the screen.
- then use `transform-origin: 0% 0%;` to set the center of rotation the top-left corner.
- then rotate it by 90 degrees with center of rotation top-left corner.
- then place the btn with `top: 50%` at the middle of the screen.
- and return the button with 50% of its width at top. As we have rotated it by 90deg, we need to use `translateX` instead of `translateY` to move our button by 50% of its width.

```css
.popup-btn{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height; 100px;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 1%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="popup-btn">
    <a href="#">Example div</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Rado, that fixed the problem! And your reply was very fast as well, a high quality response!

Comment: And i like the explination as well. If I want to turn it the other way around I can use -90degree and use a different corner of the transform-origin by setting it to for example transform-origin: 0 100%;

Comment: @Albert you can accept the answer if this was what you are looking for and if the answer is correct. Thank You!